# jquery not tracking form changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am working on primefaces application,

Initially list of items will be displayed, by clicking on the item user can edit the item.

In my case there are five tabs, if user clicks on first tab list item, 4th tab content will be displayed, clicks on second tab list item fifth tab will be displayed.

the URL will be same for all these pages

for ex: `localhost:8080/myapp/tabs.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            isInputChanged = false;
            $("#tabview").on("change", ":input", function() {
                isInputChanged = true;
            })
        });
    </script>
    <p:tabView id="tabview" activeIndex="#{myBean.tabIndex}"
        style="min-height:750px;height:auto;border:0;padding:0" dynamic="true" styleClass="hidetabheader" >

        <p:tab id="tabContents1">  
            <ui:include src="/tabContents1.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:tab>            
        <p:tab id="tabContents2">  
            <ui:include src="/tabContents2.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tabContents3">  
            <ui:include src="/tabContents3.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tabContents4">  
            <ui:include src="/tabContents4.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tabContents5">  
            <ui:include src="/tabContents5.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</ui:define>
```

While debugging through chrome
the problem is because of the same URL, input change in fourth and fifth tab are not tracked, I mean the **isInputChanged** will never becomes **true**.
In the chrome debugging tool, the source  is showing always same.

But, if I add parameter to the url like
`localhost:8080/myapp/tabs.xhtml?itemId = 100`, in the source I can see fifth tab code, and if change input the **isInputChanged** will become **true** by script.

How can I handle this situation, Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!

Comment: put  script code at the bottom of the page and then check.Also did you added jQuery library before your script code?

Comment: @Alive to Die, Yes I tried but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the following code works when localhost:8080/myapp/tabs.xhtml loads.

```
$("#tabview").on("change", ":input", function() {
    isInputChanged = true;
});
```

are you including the files after that, so that the browser will not be able to see the changes.

Like @Alive To Die commented try to put script code at the bottom of the page and then check.